Creating group functionality on a rails app
I've been trying to set up a group functionality on a rails app, but I'm having some issues with organizing the structure. So what I would like to achieve is to let user create a group and then invite other users to this group possibly just simply via sharing a link to it. The hard part is to be able to only let users whom which the link has been shared to join the group. So far I've came up with a user model
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :groups
end

and a simple group model as
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

Now I'm wondering do I need another layer here such as memberships or invitations to be able to achieve what I'm after?

yes, Invitation model with belongs_to :user, belongs_to :group

Yeah, this was what I was thinking, but I would not want to send invitations via email etc. I simply would like the creator of the group to be able to share a link with other users from where they can join. @AntonBogdanov

How the link is shared does not matter - all that  is required is a link that uniquely identifies the group to be joined.

So instead of having an invitation model, couldn't I simply have a has_secure_token for the group model? @dbugger

Yes, @Rene you just need to add a secure token to the group model so each link shared is identified by a secure token, this looks to be the only correct solution for your question

Your initial attempt does not actually work as it's a one to many relationship.
Since a Group belongs_to :user there can only ever be one single user in a group. That's a very lonely group.
What you actually want is a many to many association and for that you need to create a join table and an indirect association.
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end 

How to implement the entire feature of being able to invite users into the group is way to broad for me to go into it in detail. You need to break it down into steps and make a plan for how to implement each step and what you'll need to learn to be able to implement it.

Riffing on the answer by @max...
When you're inviting a new user to a group, you will be creating a new instance of Membership. My approach to your question is to have an attribute (field) on the Membership model called status. This can have values "pending" and "confirmed" (could be an enum field). The Membership model will also have a field called (say) "authorization_token".
The admin wishes to invite a user to a group. (S)he creates a new instance of Membership, with status 'pending' and a randomly generated authorization_token value.
This is done with a before_create callback.
Routes will be defined for the Membership model, so that my_domain/memberships/:id/:auth_token routes to the #new action of MembershipsController. This link will be included in the invitation email sent to the user, inviting them to join the group. The 'id' field refers to a new instance of Membership that the admin has created. When the user accepts the invitation (clicks on the link in the email), the status changes from pending to confirmed.
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :create_authorization_token
  after_create :invite_user

  def create_authorization_token
    self.status = 'pending'
    self.authorization_token = SecureRandom.hex(10)
  end

  def invite_user
    UserMailer.send_invitation(self.authorization_token)
  end

end

This is an outline of the approach... I've left a lot of details only broadly described. But it should get you on your way.

I really didn't want to go into how to implement it as it's very wide. This is one potential solution but I would really create a separate Invitation resource. This doesn't could be but doesn't have to be a separate model. You would invite a another user by going to GET /groups/:group_id/invitations/new and send the invitation by POST /groups/:group_id/invitations. The email contains a link to GET /groups/:group_id/members/new?token=ABCD1234... and the token is tucked into the form and verifyied when you post it to POST /groups/:group_id/members.

I would really avoid the model callbacks too. Creating the auth token should be done when you send the email so that you can resend the email if needed without reusing the same token.

@max yes, if you're going to resend the invitation, it's a good plan to replace the authorization token. I'm partial to using the Membership model for purposes of invitation because it's a perfect, and non-redundant, analog of the real world. CRUD actions on the Membership model reflect exactly the lifecycle of a real-world membership.
